# Обращение к кнопке инлайн после функции проверки

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
def finish(message, course, wallet):
    price = cg.get_price(ids='bitcoin', vs_currencies='rub')

    if message.text == 'Подтверждаю Оплату':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'♻️*Ваша заявка была создана.* \n\n_В течение 15 минут средства поступят на ваш счёт._\n\nЕсли ваша заявка не была обработана пишите сюда @Pikl1k\n\n'
                                          '_Спасибо за использование нашего обменика!_\n\n*⚠️Для возвращения в меню, пропишите команду* /start ', parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        bot.send_message(5517014795, f"*Сумма Обмена: {course}\n\n*"
                                     f"_Сумма к Получению: {float('{0:.8f}'.format(course / (price['bitcoin']['rub'] * 1.03)))} BTC\n\n_"
                                     f"_На кошелёк: {wallet['proverka']}\n\n_"
                                     f"_Время Заявки: {datetime.datetime.now()}\n\n_"
                                     f"*От Пользователя:* @{message.from_user.username}", parse_mode="Markdown")
```

Помогите пожалуйста, после данной строчки кода нужно зарегистрировать инлайн кнопку, как это сделать?

Comment: 1) Правильно ставьте метки. У вас библиотека, значит и метка `pytelegrambotapi` 2) Форматируйте код 3) Пишите подробнее. Непонятно что значит регистрация инлайн кнопки и обращение к ней. По 1) и 2) я вам покажу, но дальше делайте сами

Comment: 3) https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/e55fe962ca58aded97d676c7b36fa71519339c5c/examples/inline_keyboard_example.py ?